# Azure Machine Learning (preview) to Customer Insights

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to integrate MS Dynamics Customer Insights (CI) with the model I have built within the new Azure Machine Learning (designer). Currently, I see there is only an integration between CI and Azure Machine Learning studio (classic).

I have deployed my model behind a web service (REST) within new Azure Machine Learning however it is not getting picked up in CI. However, I am able to score/generate predictions from the API using a Python script.

Please recommend a way to integrate these two MS services or suggest an architecture where CI can pick up the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [hands-on labs](https://github.com/ArtisConsulting/customer-insights-azure-data-workshop/blob/main/README.md) which walk through the complete lifecycle for integrating Dynamics 365 Customer Insights with Azure data services. One scenario seen in [Lab 5](https://github.com/ArtisConsulting/customer-insights-azure-data-workshop/blob/main/lab05.md) is integrating the results of an Azure Machine Learning model back into Customer Insights. That walkthrough should give you one good way of accomplishing that task.

[image: workshop architecture]

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that there's a real opportunity for a more seamless integration between Azure ML and D365 (including CI). For me, I'm thinking about how cool would it be to have an ML Dataset be automatically created with D365 data that could be used in the ML designer. After which the winning model could be registered, then made available inside D365 as a field that would score things in real time.

If you an "idea" on the forum below. My team and I will upvote it!

https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/

Comment: Thank you! I have posted an idea. Please upvote. https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=60a0d0de-20a7-ea11-8b71-0003ff68c1c4